# How to remove harmony comments in webpack and hide code

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I'm working on building a personal app to learn how to build without using the create-react-app tool, which has been pretty difficult, but I'm there now.  However, when I view my code in DevTools, I see a LOT of `/* harmony import */` and Webpack functions, etc. surround my code.  Is there a webpack config option to remove this stuff?  I never see this when I use the create-react-app tool.

**Above my code**

```
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! react */ "./node_modules/react/index.js");
/* harmony import */ var react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
/* harmony import */ var react_router_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! react-router-dom */ "./node_modules/react-router-dom/esm/react-router-dom.js");
/* harmony import */ var _components_List__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ../components/List */ "./components/List.js");
/* harmony import */ var _components_Menu__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ../components/Menu */ "./components/Menu.js");
/* harmony import */ var _pages_AddUser__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ../pages/AddUser */ "./pages/AddUser.js");
/* harmony import */ var _sass_main_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ../sass/main.scss */ "./sass/main.scss");
/* harmony import */ var _sass_main_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(_sass_main_scss__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__);
function _slicedToArray(arr, i) { return _arrayWithHoles(arr) || _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) || _nonIterableRest(); }

function _nonIterableRest() { throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance"); }

function _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) { if (!(Symbol.iterator in Object(arr) || Object.prototype.toString.call(arr) === "[object Arguments]")) { return; } var _arr = []; var _n = true; var _d = false; var _e = undefined; try { for (var _i = arr[Symbol.iterator](), _s; !(_n = (_s = _i.next()).done); _n = true) { _arr.push(_s.value); if (i && _arr.length === i) break; } } catch (err) { _d = true; _e = err; } finally { try { if (!_n && _i["return"] != null) _i["return"](); } finally { if (_d) throw _e; } } return _arr; }

function _arrayWithHoles(arr) { if (Array.isArray(arr)) return arr; }
```

**Bottom of my code**

```
return react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("div", {
    className: "container"
  }, react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement(_components_Menu__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__["default"], {
    toggle: toggle,
    slidein: slidein,
    openMenu: openMenu
  }), react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("div", {
    className: "position"
  }, react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement(react_router_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["Route"], {
    path: "/",
    exact: true,
    component: _components_List__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__["default"]
  }), react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement(react_router_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["Route"], {
    path: "/add-user",
    component: _pages_AddUser__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["default"]
  })));
}

/* harmony default export */ __webpack_exports__["default"] = (App);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is the proper output of webpack.
You do not see this in `create-react-app` because `source-maps` are generated during build.
You can enable `source map` generation in webpack config to get the proper mapping to your code in dev tools.

Some resource to read: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/